# Spark connect to Kafka get error

Tags: apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka

why am I getting the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` error on spark-submit?
stacktrace shown below

```
[appadm@elk01 spark]$ bin/spark-submit --class "com.ipponusa.SparkStringConsumer" --master localhost:9092 samples/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHORT.jar 1
Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/GenTraversableOnce$class
        at kafka.utils.Pool.<init>(Pool.scala:26)
        at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStatsRegistry$.<init>(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala:61)
        at kafka.consumer.FetchRequestAndResponseStatsRegistry$.<clinit>(FetchRequestAndResponseStats.scala)
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.<init>(SimpleConsumer.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.connect(KafkaCluster.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$streaming$kafka$KafkaCluster$$withBrokers$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:345)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$streaming$kafka$KafkaCluster$$withBrokers$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:342)
```

Comment: Which version of Scala are you compiling against?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the same version of Scala as the one with which you compliled you Spark code. Check them and probably you'll need to downgrade your Scala version.